# keypress of single Quote replace with double Quote?

Tags: jquery

I want to replace keypress of single Quote with double Quote, I understand the code

```
$('html').bind('keypress', function(e)
{
   if(e.keyCode == 39)
   {
      return false;
   }
});
```

But i am not sure what to write in place of return false so that when single quote is pressed double quote is actually typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input.whatever').keypress(function() {
  var inp = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    inp.value = inp.value.replace(/a/g, 'b');
  }, 0);
});
```

**OR**

Please refer [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/4/) for your question answer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('html').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        var val = $(this).val().replace("\'","\"");
        $(this).val(val);
    }
});
```